# How to use SFSmartStore for offline data storage in native iOS application?

Tags: iphone, salesforce, offline

I am working on salesforce application. In my application, i need to store data locally for offline supporting. For this, i have seen some forums to achieve offline data storing and retrieving using sales fore smart store setup. Can anybody give some guidance how to use smart store for offline supporting.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use smart store you need Salesforce Mobile SDk configured (for Android OR iOS) 
after that please install the account editor example and study the code in here [Account Editor Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/samples_account_editor.htm#accounteditor_models) secondly,
[Using StoreCache For Offline Caching](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/entity_framework_using_storecache.htm) tutorial explains how smartstore works.